# Rails HABTM display and select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to set up in rails 3.2.0 with ruby 1.9.3 a 
`has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between two tables I have the proper join table migration set up with both foreign keys and my models are as such

student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :birthday, :id, :name, :year, :course_ids

  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses
end
```

course.rb

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :coursePrefix, :roomNumber, :name, :student_ids
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>
  <% if @student.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@student.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this student from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @student.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :birthday %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :birthday, :start_year => 1930 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :year %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :year %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.collection_select(:courses, @courses, :id, :name)%>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and student_controller.rb

```
# GET /students/new
  # GET /students/new.json
  def new
    @student = Student.new
    @courses = Course.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @student }
    end
  end

  # GET /students/1/edit
  def edit
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @courses = Course.all
  end

  # POST /students
  # POST /students.json
  def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @student, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /students/1
  # PUT /students/1.json
  def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @courses = @student.courses.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Again I am trying to get the form element to allow a student to select a course and be saved in that table under the JOIN method, however everytime I try to look for help I get different errors and cannot find a solution

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please include the errors that you're getting.

Comment: I am getting an `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error`

Comment: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: courses` Sorry forgot to include the whole message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to give access to the :courses attribute of the Student model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :birthday, :id, :name, :year, :course_ids, :courses
  #                                                           ^ ^ ^ ^
```

**Why?** Because your controller receive params formatted like this:

```
params = {
  student: {
    id: 12,
    name: "Bob the Sponge",
    courses: [5, 7], # Course ids
    etc: ...
  }
}
```

And the controller is trying to create a Student object directly with the params, so when he is trying to update the `courses` attribute of the Student, it can't because you didn't define it as accessible.

Comment: That solves my mass-assign problem, but then I get an error `undefined method each for "2":String` where the "2" is the id from the course.